# How to trigger a lambda or glue job when a file is placed in SharePoint?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, sharepoint, event-driven

If a file is placed in Microsoft SharePoint I want to trigger my AWS lambda code to bring that file to S3 (An event driven approach). Is there any way to do this? Also, I don't want to schedule it.

As of now I didnt find any solution on google.

Comment: Can't you create a flow within sharepoint that triggers on file creation and calls a webservice https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/desktop-flows/actions-reference/web#invokewebservicebase !?